# Help computing polynomial series

Tags: sequences-and-series, permutations, power-series, arithmetic

I have the following probability to be in a certain position $s_f$ at touchpoint n expressed as a polynomial series and I am struggling to compute. It goes like

$$P_{tot} (n) = (a+bx^n) \sum_{\alpha = 1}^{n-s_f+1}\left( (-1)^{\alpha+1}\alpha \sum_{k_1=1}^{n-\alpha}\sum_{k_2=k_1+1}^{n-\alpha+1}\dots\sum_{k_{\alpha}=k_{\alpha-1}+1}^{n-1} (a+bx^{k_1}). \dots . (a+bx^{k_\alpha})\right)$$

where (a+bx^k) is the probability to jump from one step s to a step s+1 at touchpoint k. I tried using Multi Binomial theorems, seeing if I can leverage stuff like Stirling numbers but with no avail. My goal is to simplify its expression so that I can then compute Expectation value of n via $<n> = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P_{tot}(n)$.
Maybe I missed a simple trick to express this simply.

For context: I obtain this expression by computing all permutations possible for certain path to reach a step. For examples:

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
    P_{tot} (s_F=2, n=2) &= E[1].E[2]\\
    \\
    P_{tot} (s_F=2, n=3) &= \overline{E}[1].E[2].E[3] E[1].\overline{E}[2].E[3]\\
    &=E[3].\left( E[1] + E[2] - 2E[1].E[2]\right)\\
\\
    P_{tot} (s_F=2, n=4) &= \overline{E}[1].\overline{E}[2].E[3].E[4] + \overline{E}[1].E[2].\overline{E}[3].E[4]+E[1].\overline{E}[2].\overline{E}[3].E[4]\\
    &=E[4].\left( E[1] + E[2] + E[3]\right.\\
    &\; - 2E[1].E[2] - 2E[1].E[3] - 2E[2].E[3]\\
    &\;\left.+3E[1].E[2].E[3]\right)
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

with $E[k]$ is the probability to move a step forward at touchpoint k and $\overline{E}[k]=1-E[k]$